# Filter points inside of a sphere with Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a set of 3D points, and I need to compute which ones are the nearest to a given point *p*.  I am wondering which could be the correct way to do it in Eigen.  So far, I have:

```
Matrix<double, Dynamic, 3> points; // The set of 3D points
Matrix<double, 1, 3> p;

// Populate the "points" matrix

...

// Fill a matrix with several copies of "p" in order to match the size
of "points"

Matrix<double, Dynamic, 3> pp(points.rows(), 3);

pp = Matrix<double, Dynamic, 1>::Ones(points.rows, 1) * p;

Matrix<double, Dynamic, 1> sq_distances = (points - pp).rowwise.squaredNorm();
Matrix<bool, Dynamic, 1> nearest_points = sq_distances < (dist_threshold * dist_threshold);
```

Can I then have some way of extracting the points in "points" that fullfill the "nearest_points" condition like in

```
Matrix<double, Dynamic, 3> nearest = points(nearest_points);
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the nearest I'd suggest:

```
int i;
double sqdist = (points.rowwise()-p).rowwise().squaredNorm().minCoeff(&i);
nearest = points.row(i);
```

For the ones in a given ball, you currently have to write one loop yourself:

```
ArrayXd sqdists = (points.rowwise()-p).rowwise().squaredNorm();
Matrix<double,Dynamic,3> nearests( (sqdists<sqradius).count(), 3 );
int count = 0;
for(int i=0; i<points.rows(); ++i)
  if(sqdists(i)<sqradius)
    nearests.row(count++) = points.row(i);
```